# Problem while communicating with WCF service using netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, timeout, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service run on Windows Server 2008 RC2 IIS 7 with no firewall. When I trying to call it with netTcpBinding binding, I get this exception:

> System.TimeoutException: The open
>   operation did not complete within the
>   allotted timeout of 00:00:30. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have
>   been a portion of a longer timeout.
>   ---> System.TimeoutException: The socket transfer timed out after
>   00:00:30. You have exceeded the
>   timeout set on your binding. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have
>   been a portion of a longer timeout.
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
>   connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond
>   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,
>   SocketFlags socketFlags)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,
>   TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)...

The method I call just returns a numeric value, nothing else, so the problem not in timeout. If I use wsHttpBinding - it works without problems. Also I added logging to method I call, so I know that it even not executed.

I made all steps to configure IIS from [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Duplex_WCF_Services_Hosted_in_IIS_Using_NetTcp.aspx). The questions are:

1. Anybody know what the problem may be?
2. How can I troubleshoot/debug this
   problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am as frustrated as you are with this misleading fault message. If I am not wrong you get this TimeoutException within the first second. I can assure you your issue either related to security or serialization problems. I took this issue to Microsoft's WCF product group, they seemed to be surprised but didn't hear back anything.

First suggestion is to look at NetTcpBinding security settings. Make sure both client and service have identical bare bones security settings to start with (such as not message encryption nor transport layer security). If you can make it work without security, step by step increase security settings.

Second suggestion some serialization problem may be crashing the service: An empty nullable field, overloaded methods mixing with operations, ambiguous contract names, invalid casts.To debug, setup tracing in your service's config settings. You can do this easily via WCF Service Config utility(SvcConfigEditor.exe). Run your service get the exception, stop it and open the generated trace logs with WCF Service Trace Viewer Tool. Both tools comes with .NET (not Visual Studio) and can be found in Program Files/Windows SDKs folder.